# File exists but when I perform operation on that file, system shows FileNotFoundException. Works when file is in dir where source code is

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

```
public void decrypt() throws Exception
{
    //opening streams
    //Error is in the line below When i try to read file from directory
    //other than the one which has .java and .class files.
    FileInputStream fis1 =new FileInputStream(file);
    File dir=new File("C:/Crypt-R/Decrypted");
    dir.mkdirs();
    file=new File(dir,file.getName() +".dec");
    FileOutputStream fos1 =new FileOutputStream(file);  
    //generating same key
    byte k[] = keyRecv.getBytes();   
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,"AES");  
    //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
    Cipher decrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);  
    decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);  
    CipherInputStream cin=new CipherInputStream(fis1, decrypt);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int read=0;
    while((read=cin.read(buf))!=-1)  //reading encrypted data from file
    {
    fos1.write(buf,0,read);       //writing decrypted data to file
    }
    //closing streams
    cin.close();
    fos1.flush();
    fos1.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,
    "File Decrypted",
    "Success..!!",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

There is a Text Editor attached to this program, file gets displayed in that Editor but when i am trying to decrypt it and it does not exist in the directory where my source code is kept then it shows file not found exception. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Windows uses backslash(\\) instead of slash (/) for file separation. Try changing the slashes to backslashes, and seeing if that helps. If not, then please provide the stack trace of exception.

Comment: @DavisBroda Windows accepts pathnames using forward slashes.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the message and stacktrace for any exceptions that you're getting, and indicate which line of the code which you posted here is producing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following things

1) Make sure you are mentioning filename that really exists in the location
   Check [Reasons for getting FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

2) Then you have to mention path like "C:\\Users\...". Make sure you use right way to mention file names on windows system

3) You have to again check similarly for FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your directories with

```
File.separator
```

Which will hold the value of `/`, `:` or `\\` depending on which platform you are on.

Comment: In Windows, the volume system is effectively treated as a "directory" off of a virtual root directory.  I know, it's not how it really works, but from the code side of things, it mostly can be simplified this way.